# The Server tag is not well formed error in a Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, servertag

I am getting the "The Server tag not well formed error". Please see the below code:

```
<ul id="wizHeader">
               <asp:Repeater ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
                   <ItemTemplate>

                       <li>
                           <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="<%# GetClassForWizardStep(Container.DataItem) %>" Font-Bold="true" ID="SideBarButton" OnClick="Step_Click" Text="<%# Eval("Name") %>" ToolTip="<%# Eval(ID) %>"></asp:LinkButton>
                       </li>

                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use <%# inside of server controls' attribute.

So if you want to use a LinkButton inside of the Repeater, you have to bind the attributes in code-behind using the Repeater.ItemDataBound event.

Example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you please correct it? What could we use inside the Server control attribute?

Comment: Well, the issue is that you can't use server code in the attribute at all. So you'll either have to write a handler for ItemDataBound on the repeater, where you fill in the attributes manually, or you have to write the link button manually, where you can use it, but you have to handle the PostBack logic on your own.

Comment: If you really have no idea what to do, I can write you a solution in your own code, but it's going to take a while longer than this :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a simple anchor tag and apply all bindings to it. And make it cause the same postback as your button was doing. Example:

```
   <a onClick="javascript:__doPostBack('<%= SideBarButton.UniqueID %>')" class="<%# GetClassForWizardStep(Container.DataItem) %>"> <%# Eval("Name") %></a>
```

After doing this, you would have to hide the link button by settings its css display property none.

Long work around. :)